# OrientDB 3.03 - What is most optimum configuration changes to improve performance of

Tags: database, orientdb, database-performance, orientdb2.2, orientdb-2.1

What is the best configuration parameter changes or tuning that we can do on OrientDB v3.03 running in distributed mode to improve performance.

Our Orientdb schema consists of:
Vertex: Two types of Vertex, one with 16 properties and other with 9 properties
Edge: Two types of edge each with 3 properties.

I am currently using the default Orientdb configuration and there is a continuous stream of records that are getting added to OrientDB.

Answer (score 1):

This is a widely discussed topic and there are many things to take into account, you should first look into the documentation listed on the following links:

[OrientDB | Performance Tuning](https://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/tuning/Performance-Tuning.html)

[OrientDB | Configuration](https://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/admin/Configuration.html)